# How to set json values came from jsp to html using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, json, jsp

Here is my code :

```
<%
response.setContentType("application/json");
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
Employee employee = new Employee("RAM","ram@gmail.com");
json.put("employee",employee);
out.println(json);
%>
```

[image: JSP & JSON & JS communication]

i need to set the json values came from jsp  into my html file. By parsing with js.
is there any idea i'm stucked over here...

if you provide code as response very helpful for me..

Comment: You can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript.

Comment: suppose if the json object having multiple employee objects so, how can i parse by javascript